# VBA Replace multiple ranges with different text

Tags: excel, vba

Im not very familiar with VBA code and was hoping someone could help me with this code.

Im trying to replace 3 different ranges with 3 different values.

The current code ive got seems to only execute the first line and the last 2 lines are ignored

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Range("B2, F1, F3:f5, F20, F22:F24") = "Enter Text Here..."
Range("C2, F2, F21") = "Select 1"
Range("C3:C10, B13:B19, B22:B25, A29:D33,F7:F16, F26:F35").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Heres the whole code;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Me.Range("B56").Value = 0 Then
    Dim xsheet As Worksheet
    Set xsheet = Sheets("Heroes_list")
        
            If xsheet.Name <> "Definitions" And xsheet.Name <> "fx" And xsheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
                xsheet.Range("A2:AC2").Copy
                xIntR = xsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                xsheet.Cells(xIntR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                MsgBox "Saved Successfully!"
            End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
Else
    If Me.Range("B56").Value = 1 Then _
        
    MsgBox "Not allowed, please revise costs, conflicts and all fields are filled correctly."
     End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


    


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Heroes_list").Copy '  golly im good
With ActiveWorkbook
    ChDir "C:\Users\Evane\Documents\Calix\Photoshop_excel_imports\"
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Evane\Documents\Calix\Photoshop_excel_imports\hero" & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "Exported successfully!"

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Me.Range("B52").Value = 1 Then _
MsgBox "The current effect combination for this PRIMARY ATTACK is invalid,Please ensure that if negative effects are listed, the list starts with atleast 1 negative status effect or that the effect list starts at line 1."
End

If Me.Range("B54").Value = 1 Then _
MsgBox "The current effect combination for this SECONDARY ATTACK is invalid,Please ensure that if negative effects are listed, the list starts with atleast 1 negative status effect or that the effect list starts at line 1."
End


If Me.Range("A49").Value > 1 Then _
MsgBox "Element conflict! The same element cannot be listed under both weakness and resistance!"
End
End Sub

Public Sub PasteasValue()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("b56") = 1 Then Sheets("Hero_creation").CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red!
If Range("b56") = 1 Then Sheets("Hero_creation").CommandButton1.Font.Strikethrough = True  'strikethrough text
If Range("b56") = 0 Then Sheets("Hero_creation").CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green!
If Range("b56") = 0 Then Sheets("Hero_creation").CommandButton1.Font.Strikethrough = False 'No strik through text
End Sub

'New Code

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.address = "$B$2" Or Target.address = "$F$1" Or Target.address = "$F$20" Or Target.address = "$C$2" Or Target.address = "$F$2" Or Target.address = "$F$3" Or Target.address = "$F$4" Or Target.address = "$F$5" Or Target.address = "$F$21" Or Target.address = "$F$22" Or Target.address = "$F$23" Or Target.address = "$F$24" Or Target.address = "$C$3" Or Target.address = "$C$4" Or Target.address = "$C$5" Or Target.address = "$C$6" Or Target.address = "$C$7" Or Target.address = "$C$8" Or Target.address = "$C$9" Or Target.address = "$C$10" Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then  '  case a cell was emptied
         Let Application.EnableEvents = False
         Let Target.Value = "Enter Text Here..."
         Let Application.EnableEvents = True

        Else  '  case a text was entered
            With Target.Font
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Else
    ' Target is Not a cell to be acted on
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Range("B2, F1, F3:f5, F20, F22:F24") = "Enter Text Here..."
    Range("C2, F2, F21") = "Select 1"
    Range("C3:C10, B13:B19, B22:B25, A29:D33,F7:F16, F26:F35").ClearContents
    End Sub
```

Comment: It works just fine when I test it. Do you have any other code in the workbook?

Comment: a fair bit of other stuff, do you think there could be a conflict?

Comment: That's what it seems like to me. Have you tried it in a workbook that has only that code in it? If so, i am pretty sure you will see that it's doing what you tell it.

Comment: just tried it in another workbook, youre right. Not sure what i can be conflicting with tho. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have any code for `Worksheet_Change` event in any of the `Worksheet` object or `Workbook_SheetChange` event in `ThisWorkBook` object? Changing the value could trigger them. Stepping through your code to see what is it doing will help too. @WontonAnimalChin

Comment: i do have have a few of those. Im trying to look through the code to see what the conflict is.
I shared the whole VBA code on the original post, thanks for the help

Comment: If you do not want the action of `CommandButton3_Click` to be affected by the event, insert `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the lines and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after that (you did that in `Worksheet_Change`!) Btw, you do not need to use `Let`. (Sounds like you are making some cool game!) @WontonAnimalChin

Comment: Didn't quite seem to solve my issues, but thanks for the suggestion!
and cheers, hopefully its worth all this effort haha

Comment: it seems to be my Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() function i have. Not sure why tho :/

Comment: I can almost guarantee that you'll get a better idea of where the problem lies, if you try *stepping* through the code line by line (per @RaymondWu) while keeping a close eye on what's being affected by each line of code. Here's a link to some [excellent advice about debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx) from VBA guru Chip Pearson. (I'd also recommended bookmarking his [list of VBA solutions](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) for future reference.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @ashleedawg ill take a look! im still working thought it now haha

Comment: I so I just combined the worksheet_change and worksheet_calculate with the stuff under worksheet_calculate first and everything now works fine! thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @WontonAnimalChin If an answer resolve your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer (You can only accept 1 answer if there are multiple submitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Worksheet_Calculate` event, you are missing the `If` in your `End`s which ends up as a [End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement) statement, this stops the entire procedure immediately

I have also removed `_` after `Then`.

Full code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("B52").Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "The current effect combination for this PRIMARY ATTACK is invalid,Please ensure that if negative effects are listed, the list starts with atleast 1 negative status effect or that the effect list starts at line 1."
    End If
    
    If Me.Range("B54").Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "The current effect combination for this SECONDARY ATTACK is invalid,Please ensure that if negative effects are listed, the list starts with atleast 1 negative status effect or that the effect list starts at line 1."
    End If
        
    If Me.Range("A49").Value > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Element conflict! The same element cannot be listed under both weakness and resistance!"
    End If
End Sub
```

I assume `Worksheet_Calculate` is triggered because you have formula(s) from other cells that are affected by the change so if you do not want that to be triggered, manipulate `Application.EnableEvents` property:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("B2, F1, F3:f5, F20, F22:F24") = "Enter Text Here..."
    Range("C2, F2, F21") = "Select 1"
    Range("C3:C10, B13:B19, B22:B25, A29:D33,F7:F16, F26:F35").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I bet Raymond figured that out by [stepping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750005/vba-replace-multiple-ranges-with-different-text#comment123292793_69750005) through the code. 

Comment: @ashleedawg I'm lucky that nothing is at stake! The code stopping at `End` immediately got me curious and that's where I notice the "typo"

Comment: Legend @RaymondWu! Thanks so much for the help, and thanks to everyone else too!